# How to delete rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a '-' in my dataframe under grades column and all the entries in this column is an object. So when I tried to convert it int by using `df.astype(str).astype(int)`. This '-' is not allowing it to happen and throwing an error.

Can someone suggest me a code to replace '-' with 0 ?

Thanks for help

Comment: df.replace({'-':'0'},regex=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to replace in specific column

```
df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].replace(regex="-",value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
 df.replace(to_replace="-", value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or could convert the "-" to null values:

```
    df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
```